How to Find Highest High Between Two different Conditions?
enter image description here
Like this , could anyone teach me how to find the highest high between two red circles(conditions, the first one crossover the upper ,and the second crossunder the lower) on the bollinger bands? I have totally no idea how to do that

well, there s no need to answer anymore, ive ald finished it by myself, thx

Then you can share your answer for future readers?
